# \footfullcite does NOT give the full citation (biblatex, beamer)

Tags: beamer, biblatex, footnotes, citing

As the title says, the command `\footfullcite{test}` does not give the full citation, but only the label "test", "test1" and "test2", respectively. I'm using biblatex and the beamer class (downloaded yesterday, so hopefully the newest versions).

Any ideas? :(

Code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=authortitle]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{vorlage.bib}

 @article{test1,
    author  = {Shen Lin and Brian W. Kernighan},
    title   = {An Effective Heuristic Algorithm for the Travelling-Salesman Problem},
    journal = {Operations Research},
    volume  = {21},
    year    = {1973},
    pages   = {498--516},
 }

@BOOK{test,
  title = {The Infamous Test},
  publisher = {Testington Test},
  year = {2007},
  author = {John Doe},
  address = {Testville},
}

@ARTICLE{test2,
  author = {Testi, T.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Testartikel},
  journal = {Testjournal}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{vorlage.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Introduction and motivation - the title}
\section[Motivation]{Introduction and motivation}
test text \footfullcite{test}\\test text 1 \footfullcite{test1}\\test text 2 \footfullcite{test2}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

here the result:

[image: beamer slide]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I think I get the desired output. Have you run `pdflatex`, then `bibtex`, then `pdflatex` twice?

Comment: actually I used the MikTeX standard, which is pdfLaTeX + MakeIndex + BibTeX. I did this several times with and without deleting the .aux file. I also tried as you said: pdfLaTeX + BibTeX twice, but this doesn't change anything...

Comment: If your biblatex is up to date, it wants biber not biblatex. Either run `biber` or add `backend=bibtex` to the options when loading biblatex.

Comment: I'm glad it's sorted out.  Since it was a simple one-off issue this question will probably be closed.

Comment: FWIW, I have this problem as well and the comments were helpful in solving it.

Comment: I had this problem as well. Thanks @PaulStanley. I did backend=bibtex. Most other forums suggest using biber, but that did not work for me. (It used to work for me previously). Also, bibtex is better integrated to my editor

Comment: @PaulStanley Thanks. \usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex} worked

Comment: wtf is the point of closing this question? I had the same problem and Paul's comment provided the solution. Stack Exchange has really fallen to the pedants.