# Footnote references in Beamer

Tags: beamer, biblatex, footnotes

I would like to add full reference in the footnote, in Beamer. I am using MiKTeX 2.9 with TeXNicCenter 2.0 Alpha 3 build 1118.

I know about this question
[Place bibliography items at bottom of frame](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5836/place-bibliography-items-at-bottom-of-frame). I tried to do what is recommended in the chosen answer
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6015/35656.

Instead of obtaining the desired output, the footnote contained only the id of the reference. I looked more on tex.SE, and found this closed question
[\footfullcite does NOT give the full citation (biblatex, beamer)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116826/footfullcite-does-not-give-the-full-citation-biblatex-beamer). I saw in a comment to the question that, when using MikTex, I should add "backend=bibtex" to the options. This didn't help me. I keep receiving the biblatex error "patching footnotes failed".

I paste below the code.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\usepackage[style=authortitle,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\bibliography{foo}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Here is text \footfullcite{ref01}. % this writes ref01 in footnote

Here is text \fullcite{ref01}. % this writes ref01 in place
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of `\bibliography{foo}` you should use `\addbibresource{foo.bib}`. Which version of MiKTeX do you use? With a recent version there should be no problem.

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina. I am using MiKTeX 2.9 with TeXNicCenter 2.0 Alpha 3 (build 1118). I changed to \addbibresource{foo.bib} and still did not work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You don't need backend=bibtex with a current miktex.

This here works fine for me

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Here is text \footfullcite{westfahl:space}. % this writes ref01 in footnote
Here is text \fullcite{westfahl:space}. % this writes ref01 in place
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Make sure that you compile pdflatex, **biber**, pdflatex, pdflatex. You will perhaps have to change the configuration of texniccenter so that is calls `biber file.bcf` or `biber file` instead of `bibtex file.aux` or `bibtex file`.

You should also check if your system is up-to-date. Run the update manager in admin **and** user mode.

Comment: Indeed, I replaced bibtex with biber in TexnicCenter configuration. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, now I tried to build another project in TexnicCenter, and it didn't build the bibliography. I had to switch back from biber to bibtex and it worked, but I have the feeling that this is not the way.